# sysprocesses program_name does not contain hex id

Tags: ssms

I'm trying to identify long running processes, and the solutions I've been finding (including on StackOverflow) often involve using the hex part of the program_name from the sysprocesses table, and then matching it to the job_id of the sysjobs table.

My problem is that the program_name column is sometimes completely empty, and never contains a hex string, just a name in plain English. (By the way, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008.)

I'm probably missing something very trivial, but I'd appreciate if someone could point it out to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is very trivial, but I'm a novice.  So someone explained to me that not every entry listed in the sysprocesses table is a SQL Agent job, and only SQL Agent jobs have the hex string as a part of program_name.  Since I didn't have any SQL Agent jobs running at the time, none of the entries in sysprocesses had a hex part (which is OK, because I only need to identify long-running SQL Agent jobs).

I hope this is helpful to another beginner out there!